# Spark : Java : Why Dataset.show() is not showing all fields when using custom encoder?

Tags: java-8

While using map() on Dataset, it is not returning all fields.

code snippet:

```
RecordParser parser = new RecordParser();
Dataset<CensusData> censusData = 
records.map(parser,Encoders.bean(CensusData.class));

censusData.show(40);
```

The above code is returning only 5 fields, whereas it has 13 fields.

output:

```
+----------+---------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------+
|activityId|contentId|daypart|deviceTypeId|errorMsg|            genreId| 
+----------+---------+-------+------------+--------+-------------------+
|      null|     null|   null|        null|    null|               null| 
|         4|     0002|      1|           1|    null|                DR1| 
|         4|     0004|      1|           2|    null|Children (0-12 yrs)| 
|          |     0018|      1|           3|    null|      Entertainment|
```

How can i solve this problem?

Edit:
Details:
Java version : 8
Spark version : 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the issue, the Bean class must have getters and setters for all fields you want.